# pygame import error in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pygame

when I import pygame using eclipse on my mac, there's a import error:
[image]

However, I can still run this program correctly, So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: have you try `pygame.__init__()` (with 2 underscore in front of and at the end of `init`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to quick fix you can do:

*PyDev Package Explorer>right click your project>properties>PyDev - PYTHONPATH>External Libraries>Add source folder>PythonX.X(version where you installed pygame)/Lib/site-packages/pygame*

this will include one external library for this project, but you should check if you are working with the right python version you installed.
I have 3 versions of python, pygame is only on Python2.6, so all my new projects that use pygame must have python2.6 syntax and interpreter python26.

To check your interpreter settings:

*Window(menu)>Preferences>PyDev>Interpreter - Python>New>interpreter name you can put anything you may remember, interpreter executable find the python.exe and put the path there, OK.*

Now you have added the entry for the interpreter, if you look down in the same window, into Libraries you can add many packages you want the interpreter to look for to resolve names and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

They make Pygame for every version of Python. I have it for Python 3.4 it came out in March 2014. If you are getting the error there is no module named Pygame. It is because Pygame is not in Python's path or you have the wrong version of Pygame for your current version of Python. You can find more Pygame downloads here that arnt on pygame.org. Click on the blue word Pygame at the top and it will take you to the proper section of the page.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Download the one you need for your Python version. If you hold the mouse over it it should show more info about the version in a tiny pop up. I am on windows but it found the path by itself. I'm not sure if it will for mac.